# How to sort cards in by in array acc. to the color type

Tags: java, sorting

I just want to sort the **cards** in payers hand by colours in order Spade, Heart ,Club, Diamnod....right

I have count them and know want to sort....

**Note:** color sort had already done in upper method i want to sort now in no.s with in same colors...

```
    public static void noSort(Card temp[]){
    int S=0,H=0,C=0,D=0;
    for(Card x: temp){
        if(x.cardType=="Spade")
            S++;
        else if(x.cardType=="Heart")
            H++;
        else if(x.cardType=="Club")
            C++;
        else
            D++;            
    }
    System.out.println("S: " + S + " H: " + H + " C: " + C + " D: " + D);

    int loc=0;
    Card swap=temp[loc];
    for(loc=0;loc<S;loc++){
        for(int i=0;i<S;i++){
            if(temp[i].cardType=="Spade"){
                if(temp[i].cardValue>temp[i+1].cardValue);{
                    swap=temp[i];
                    temp[i]=temp[i+1];
                    temp[i+1]=swap; 
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you're comparing String values using `==`. Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: Why you do not use Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) ?

Comment: Thanks all the problem was the ";" placed in end of last if statement

Answer (score 1):

So implement `Comparable` interface and override `compareTo` method for your `Card`. And call `Collections.sort` method for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

My friend for color sorting you can try Dutch national flag problem  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem,

and for number sorting within in the same color you can use [selection sort](http://java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/selection-sort/) or quick sort